# Как добавить скролл в сафари для таблицы?

Tags: html, css

```css
.single__wrap-table {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 500px;
}

th {
  width: 40%;
}

td {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="single__wrap-table">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente possimus necessitatibus totam aliquid nobis exercitationem autem, deserunt id provident aut. Commodi officiis expedita, similique magni blanditiis dicta minima laborum omnis!</th>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente possimus necessitatibus totam aliquid nobis exercitationem autem, deserunt id provident aut. Commodi officiis expedita, similique magni blanditiis dicta minima laborum omnis!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente possimus necessitatibus totam aliquid nobis exercitationem autem, deserunt id provident aut. Commodi officiis expedita, similique magni blanditiis dicta minima laborum omnis!</th>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente possimus necessitatibus totam aliquid nobis exercitationem autem, deserunt id provident aut. Commodi officiis expedita, similique magni blanditiis dicta minima laborum omnis!</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Ничего непонятно. Просто код, и что в нем не работает?

Comment: @DiD, на айфонах не показывается скролл для таблицы